# Python: cannot imoport keras, ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, keras

I just update keras package to 1.1.0 version. But it canot be properly imported. 
Error message:

```
import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

It seems that the new version requires TensorFlow. I use anaconda in windows 10.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed by changing backend setup to 'theano'

Comment: Did you change anything? I have the same problem but no clue how to make that change